# as.numeric produces weird values - popular solutions does not work

Tags: r

I have one row only data frame (its subtracted from bigger df) and I tried to use it as vector of values. I tried to subset first row using `x[1,]`(actually only `x` here works but i think this is more "formal"). So i did this

```
rownames(x)=c() #to make sure nothing messes up with the output
```

`x[1,]`

```
#here is my output
     2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
```

`1     4.2  2.1  1.1  0.5  2.3    2`

After research I know there are couple solution to this (I also red R FAQ 7.10) and most common is this:
`as.numeric(as.character(x[1,]))`

and the result is

`1428.0 1203.0    1.1    0.5    2.3    2.0`

So as you can see first two values are "weird". I also tried `as.numeric(levels(x[1,]))[as.integer(x[1,])]` which produced NAs. What is interesting is fact that when I refer to first column it works fine.

```
as.numeric(as.character(x[,1]))
[1] 4.2
```

So am I doing something wrong or the problem lies in my csv files formatting? Unfortunately I can not post reproducible example since I do not understand cause of this problem. I have only one hint: the `x[1,]` was subtracted from huge list containing multiple (20+) similar data frames.

I know this question was asked here several times, but from what I have noticed all suggested solutions works for post authors. Sadly, they dont work for me. Thank you in advance.

As requested i am posting `head(dput(x[1,]))`. I put it into JPEG files because I cant post such long post. Hope I did not miss any page (keep in mind this is only `head()` output:

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMl4P.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDoNm.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoQmG.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKmCc.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ufQO.jpg
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weAPI.jpg
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL44L.jpg
  [8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2vjN.jpg
  [9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNB6w.jpg
```

My `dput(x[1,])` is very long, here is `dput(head(x[1,]))`:

`structure(list("2000" = structure(1428L, .Label = c("", "-0.004", "-0.008", "-0.01", "-0.012", "-0.013", "-0.014", "-0.025", "-0.026", "-0.028", "-0.029", "-0.032", "-0.034", "-0.039", "-0.04", "-0.045", "-0.051", "-0.053", "-0.054", "-0.059", "-0.061", "-0.062", "-0.065", "-0.071", "-0.074", "-0.075", "-0.086", "-0.088", "-0.09", "-0.092",`

Comment: Please provide `dput(x[1,])`

Comment: `dput(x[1,])` is very big, actually bigger than my console can display. From what I know stackoverflow does not allow posting links to any files. So I am just posting only last part of the output: `    "2002" = 1.1, "2003" = 0.5, "2004" = 2.3, "2005" = 2), .Names = c("2000", 
"2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
1  4.2  2.1  1.1  0.5  2.3    2`  Rest is just various numbers.

Comment: The please provide `dput(head((x[1,]))` and please put it into the question itself

Comment: Belive it or not, but `dput(head(x[1,]))` is still to big to post here so here are couple of first lines: `structure(list("2000" = structure(1428L, .Label = c("", "-0.004", 
"-0.008", "-0.01", "-0.012", "-0.013", "-0.014", "-0.025", "-0.026", 
"-0.028", "-0.029", "-0.032", "-0.034", "-0.039", "-0.04", "-0.045", 
"-0.051", "-0.053", "-0.054", "-0.059", "-0.061", "-0.062", "-0.065", 
"-0.071", "-0.074", "-0.075", "-0.086", "-0.088", "-0.09", "-0.092", `. I replaced some ``` in original output to just `"` so it dont mess up the formatting

Comment: I've asked to post it into the question, not comments

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further research and lot of trial and error I managed to form workaround of this issue. I tried using variation of `droplevels` functions but with no success. So I moved little bit back in my code to `read.csv` part and added `stringsAsFactors=F` and both `as.numeric` and `as.character` works properly (they display values as they are). So I did not actually find any way to transform those data to way i desired, instead I "traveled back in time" and prevent my problem from happening.